# Reopen Terminal windows after restarting

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, session

In Mac, if I have a few Terminal windows open and I restart the computer or quit Terminal, the windows that were open last are opened again with their working directories and command histories retained.

Is there a way to similarly reopen Ubuntu Terminal windows?

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? Unity (the Ubuntu default) or something else? And which terminal emulator are you using? (I don't know what the Ubuntu default is these days — gnome-terminal?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically it depends upon the chosen desktop.  The question has been asked here and there without any good answers.  For gnome-terminal, a commonly proposed solution is adding the `--save-config` option, e.g.,

```
gnome-terminal --save-config=/home/whatever/foo
```

There is also the `dconf-editor` which might be effective, depending on what applications you use.

In either case, those would only restore a *shell* to a given working directory; restoring programs running within the shell seems to be glossed over generally (except for the rare case where the application also has session support).

Further reading:

- [How to Remember and Restore Running Applications on Next Logon](http://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/remember-running-applications-ubuntu/)
- [How to Auto Save Sessions in Ubuntu 14.04 Using Dconf-Editor](http://sourcedigit.com/14072-auto-save-sessions-ubuntu-14-04-using-dconf-editor/)
- [Some fast way to save and restore tabs of Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310705/some-fast-way-to-save-and-restore-tabs-of-terminal)
- [How to remember multiple tabs' session in terminal? (Alike FF session manager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048474/how-to-remember-multiple-tabs-session-in-terminal-alike-ff-session-manager)
- [gnome-save-session won't save gnome-terminals](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=981832)
- [gnome-terminal profiles are not being loaded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631481/gnome-terminal-profiles-are-not-being-loaded)

Comment: Option “--save-config” is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal (3.28.2)

Answer (score 0):

I too was annoyed after switching from mac to windows, couldnt get to restore terminals (WSL) and would restart with fresh window. What worked for me was that I installed ubuntu via VMWare, and VMWare by default suspends upon restart of windows, hence whenever I reboot and reopen the VMWare app, I find all applications, including terminal tabs in same (restored) state as it was before reboot. Hope this helps others.